# Heading size of paragraph

Tags: html, html-heading

In [This Example](http://jsfiddle.net/PnP64/) the header is not the normal size of a header. Please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the "Normalized CSS" checkbox on the left? It's using a [CSS reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset).

From [the jsFiddle docs](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html?highlight=normalized#choose-framework):

> [...]Next is the Normalized CSS checkbox, selected by default. If selected, the fiddle will be rendered with [normalize.css](http://jsfiddle.net/css/normalize.css) which is removing most of the browser styling of many HTML tags.

Comment: Okay Thank you! I didn't realize it was that simple.